# Json запрос с массивом

Tags: c#, json

Здравствуйте!

Нужно отправить запрос типа

```
{
    "apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
    "modelName": "TrackingDocument",
    "calledMethod": "getStatusDocuments",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentNumber": "20400048799000",
                "Phone":""
            },
            {
                "DocumentNumber": "20400048799001",
                "Phone":""
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Запрос отправляю методом

```
private async Task NewMethod1()
        {
            object dataObject1;
            string dataObject;

            NovaP bodyStr = new NovaP();
            bodyStr.ModelName = "TrackingDocument";
            bodyStr.CalledMethod = "getStatusDocuments";
            bodyStr.MethodProperties = new RefProp {
                Documents = new string[] { "str"}
            };
            bodyStr.ApiKey = "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]";

            string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyStr);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers

            var uri = "http://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/TrackingDocument/getStatusDocuments?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                dataObject = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dataObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataObject);
                richTextBox1.Text = dataObject1.ToString();
            }
```

Проблема возникает при создании `Documents`. Не получается создать в данном формате запрос.

Comment: дак чего вы туда массив строк пытаетесь записать если у вас там массив объектов нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Document
{
    public class Document(string doc, string phone)
    {
        DocumentNumber = doc;
        Phone = phone;
    }
    public string DocumentNumber {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

в `RefProp`:

```
{
    ...
    public List<Document> Documents {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

вместо:

```
bodyStr.MethodProperties = new RefProp {
    Documents = new string[] { "str"}
};
```

будет:

```
bodyStr.MethodProperties = new RefProp {
    Documents = new List<Document>() { new Document("20400048799000",""), new Document("20400048799001","")}
};
```